# w/Url.Action when targeting an Index Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, area, ambiguous, url.action

I'm running into a situation where a "fully qualified" route is not being generated when it needs to be. The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
        var junk = Url.Action("Index2", "Reference", new { area = "Admin" });
        junk = Url.Action("Index", "Reference", new { area = "Admin", memberID = 47 });
```

The first call to Url.Action() produces **/Admin/Reference/Index2**. The second call produces **/Admin/Reference**, I guess because "Index" is a default identifier.

Unfortunately, the route mapping (which I haven't modified since it was generated by VS2010) will of course process the second route as being a call for a Reference method on the Admin controller in the root area. There's no way the route resolver can know that the second link is really intended for the Index handler of the Reference controller in the Admin area.

One obvious workaround is to not have an Index method in a controller inside an area. But that seems ugly. I'm interested in a better/more robust approach.

Comment: Okay, never mind. Turns out the problem was a combination of an incorrect area name and an HttpPost attribute on a method that needs to be able to respond to GET. Please disregard.

Comment: you can post your solution as an answer below and then accept it. (By clicking the big check mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, never mind. Turns out the problem was a combination of an incorrect area name and an HttpPost attribute on a method that needs to be able to respond to GET. Please disregard